# Why I can't force UIViewController orientation on iPad to be portrait as a framework developer?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

our client specified that the only available orientation for the device should be in portrait mode. It is easy to set that in the application, but I am **developing a framework.** This is why I add the following code to every ViewController which is available in our framework:

​

```
   override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }

    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override open var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
    }
```

The problem is  that it does not work on **iPad...** It works well on all iphones, but does not on iPad.. Maybe someone knows how to achieve desired behavior **with specific ViewControllers?**

​

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default project-level setting for an iPad app is that Requires Full Screen (in App Target -> General) is *not* checked. This means that your code is not even being consulted. What you're doing would work only if every app that uses your framework has that checkbox *checked*.

Comment: Are there some ways, or am I doomed?
Can I enable Requires Full Screen with code?

Comment: Well, we're all doomed. :) But basically, no, as a framework, you are a guest, at the mercy of the app target settings in this regard. "Can I enable Requires Full Screen with code?" No, because it is set thru the Info.plist before any code runs and cannot be changed.

Comment: Because iPhones don't support multi tasking views, so the app *always* has the fulll screen.